# Would a badblocks read-only test be sufficient to verify data integrity/drive health? (Badblocks/Linux)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-transfer, data-validation

As the title suggests I have a HDD which I haven't powered on for the last year or so and I wanted to check for bad sectors. Usually I do a destructive 4 pass read-write test with badblocks to test new drives `badblocks -b 4096 -wsv /dev/sdx`. Since the disk is filled to the brim with data and I don't have any other spare drives to migrate the data to I was thinking about doing a read-only pass with badblocks to see if the Relocated Sector Count value changes. I would do that by running a smart test `smartctl -A /dev/sdx` before and after the read-only test and see if there is any difference. Is this a valid way of figuring out the amount of bad sectors?

Would the read-only test would be able to determine if there is any data corruption? Are there any better and more recent tools for this job besides badblocks?

Comment: badblocks does not test data integrity. it only tests the function of the disks surface. data corruption cause by any other source than dead sectors will not be detected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, are there any more recent tools to check for data integrity in ext4?

Comment: fsck or it could be called efsck or maybe even fsck.ext depending on your distro.  However, it just checks the file system which is the table of contents

Answer (score 0):

badblocks checks to see if all sectors are readable/writeable depending on options used.  It is useful as a first step because bad sectors will cause issues further down the line.

However, badblocks is more useful because of SMART built into any sata drive and even many older drives have it.  SMART has values like CRC errors, or uncorrectable errors, but SMART only checks the sectors it looks at.  So badblocks will force the hard drive SMART to check every sector on the disk.

I have yet to find a program which reads a sector and then checks smart to see if the errors have increased before reading the next sector which would be ideal as then you could pinpoint the error to a specific file.

However, even the hard drive has ECC or error correcting technology it can only correct so many bad bits.  After that the damage is permanent.

fsck checks the file system, but the filesystem is the equivalent to the table of contents in a book and not individual pages.

Now some files like zip files have CRC or other error detection technology built in and errors can be detected but not corrected.  A CRC failure would indicate the file was damaged, but not be able to correct it.  However, many do not.

Now if you take precaution in advance there are a few option like QuickPar which generates parity data which can be used to repair files.

However, the parity data would have to re-run QuickPar or similar to update the parity data every time the contents of a file changes.  This is fine if you want to put the drive on a shelf for 6 months, but if your actively changing files every day this would be tedious to say the least.  The program has an option to determine how much damage can be recovered, but the higher the setting the more disk space it will use and it will take time quite possible a great deal of time to complete.

Above that we have RAID mirroring and levels 5 and 6 which can lose 1 or more disks and the other drives will rebuild it.  However, the parity/repair data is all handled automatically by a hardware or software RAID controller.  The down side here is it will be much more costly money wise.